# Prometheus metrics at gateway: UNKNOWN instead of a path in uri

Tags: spring-boot, spring-mvc, prometheus, api-gateway

I'm using prometheus metrics in my project.
In the gateway, I see UNKNOWN in the metrics

```
http_server_requests_seconds_count{exception="None",method="PUT",outcome="SUCCESS",status="200",uri="UNKNOWN",} 8.0
```

Spring sets this value in WebMvcTags in the uri method because it doesn't find a pattern.
How to make a path instead of UNKNOWN?
Should I set a pattern?

Comment: Did you find any solution?